# C++ regex negated forward lookup

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

OK, this is silly but I'm struggling with it and I cannot find the answer.

How can I create a `Regex` that matches anything till an occurrence of an specific phrase?
e.g. anything till "tada".

So if the input string is: "blah blah foo bar tadada bee da!", the `regex` should match "blah blah foo bar " and if the input string is "blah blah" it matches the whole string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be:

```
(.*)(?:tada)|(.*)
```

Then just grab the first capture group.